# Is there a library similar to bitcore?

Tags: javascript, api

Is there a library like insight / bitcoin that interacts with Monero to create an API to scan the blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find some examples over at https://github.com/moneroexamples

However, Monero's blockchain does not offer as much information like Bitcoin's blockchain and you will fail to query balances of specific addresses or transaction details unless you have access to the private keys.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things over at https://github.com/monero-integrations

Honestly though, the JSON RPC interface is pretty simple to use. https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/